# Transport Database Query through Web Services without using Dataset

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, serialization

Understanding that passing Datasets through web services is a bit heavy (and almost if not completely unconsumable to non .NET clients) what is the best way to prep database query results that don't map to known types for transport through web services in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return your results as collections of Data Transfer Objects. These would be simple objects with nothing but properties. There would be one property for each "column" of your result.

I don't know what you mean about passing the query. That's not normally done. You might pass criteria for the query, but not the query itself.